# Example of structure where the exchange principle for model-theoretic algebraic closure does not hold?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I need an example of a structure such that the exchange principle for model-theoretic algebraic closure does not hold, which is, it is not true that whenever $a \in alc(b, A) $ and $a \notin alc(A) $ we have $b \in alc(a, A)$, where $A$ is a set of parameters. I know that it holds in minimal and o-minimal structures, so I have to think about something that does not belong in these classes, but I still have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $A=\emptyset$ for simplicity. What we're looking for is a structure in which some infinite set $B$ of elements all "single out" some element $a$ in a definable way; the idea then is that $a\in acl(b)$ (indeed $dcl(b)$) for each $b\in B$, but since $B$ is infinite we can't obviously "reverse" the process.

There are many ways to do this. I'm particularly a fan of the following structure $\mathcal{S}$:

- The underlying set of $\mathcal{S}$ is $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$, the set of infinite sequences of natural numbers.
- The signature of $\mathcal{S}$ is the "backshift" operation, $$p:(a_0,a_1,a_2,a_3,...)\mapsto (a_1,a_2,a_3,...).$$

Note that we crucially do **not** have any "lateral" ordering: there's no sense in which $(1,1,1,1,...)$ is "to the left of" $(2,2,2,2,...)$, and so forth.

It's easy to check (think about automorphisms) that we always have  $$acl(\alpha)=dcl(\alpha)=\{p^n(\alpha): n\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ In particular, we have $$\alpha\in acl(\beta)\mbox{ and }\beta\in acl(\alpha)\quad\iff\quad \alpha=\beta.$$ So exchange fails **everywhere**.

*(Note that we can tweak this example to get a structure where exchange holds for $acl$ but fails for $dcl$: just work with $2^\mathbb{N}$ instead of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.)*

Comment: why is $acl(\alpha) = \lbrace p^n (\alpha) : n \in \mathbb{N} \rbrace $ ?

Comment: @Matteo Think about automorphisms. Remember that if $a$ is in the algebraic closure of $Q$ then the orbit of $a$ under the group of automorphisms fixing $Q$ is finite. Now suppose $x$ is not a prefix of $y$, can you find lots of automorphisms fixing $y$ but moving $x$? (It may help to first consider the case where $x$ is an immediate successor of $y$.)

Comment: @MatteoCasarosa When I said "$x$ is an immediate successor of $y$" in my hint, I meant $p(x)=y$. Note that there's a natural partial ordering on $\mathcal{S}$ induced by $p$: $a\le b$ iff we have $a=b$ or $a=p^n(b)$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$; it may be easier to think up automorphisms of this poset than of $\mathcal{S}$ itself.

Comment: Excuse me but, from what you have written in the body of your answer, shouldn't the question be: «can you find an infinite quantity of automorphisms fixing $\alpha$  but moving $\beta$, where $\alpha$ is not a prefix of $\beta$?». If I can, that proves that $\beta$ must be of the form $\beta = p^n(\alpha)$ in order to be in the algebraic closure of $\alpha$.